# How come Queuable apex accepts sobjects where as future methods doesn't?

Tags: asynchronous

As we know we cant pass sobjects to @future method due stale of data during the processing time,where as not same in case of Queable apex.How exactly its working by using Sobjects here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct that although we can pass non-primitive data-types to  [Queueable Apex](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_queueing_jobs.htm), that data can also be stale. This has not been covered in any documentation as far as I have seen.

Below is the simple test on Account `Async Apex Test`:

Apex:

```
public static void testAsync(){
    Account acc = [SELECT Id, Name FROM Account WHERE Id='0010K000027JATrQAO'];
    System.enqueueJob(new AsyncExecutionExample(acc));
    acc.Name = acc.Name + '_New';
    update acc;
    System.debug('testAsync Acc => '+acc); 
    System.debug('testAsync time => '+Datetime.now().getTime()); 
}

public class AsyncExecutionExample implements Queueable {
    public Account acc{get;set;}
    public Long gtime{get;set;}
    public AsyncExecutionExample(Account acc){
        this.gtime = Datetime.now().getTime();
        this.acc = acc;
    }
    public void execute(QueueableContext context) {
        System.debug('AsyncExecutionExample Start Time => '+gtime);
        System.debug('AsyncExecutionExample Execute Time => '+Datetime.now().getTime());
        System.debug('AsyncExecutionExample Acc => '+acc);     
    }
}
```

Now, when you run `testAsync()` in anonymous apex, you will get below logs:

Synchronous log:

```
testAsync Acc => Account:{Id=0010K000027JATrQAO, Name=Async Apex Test_New, RecordTypeId=0120K000000TO5KQAW}
testAsync time => 1566978354053
```

Async Queue log:

```
AsyncExecutionExample Start Time => 1566978353918
AsyncExecutionExample Execute Time => 1566978355727
AsyncExecutionExample Acc => Account:{Id=0010K000027JATrQAO, Name=Async Apex Test, RecordTypeId=0120K000000TO5KQAW}
```

**As you see, Queue Apex got the account before update and the account has been updated before Queue executed. As noticed, queue has stale data of Account. So, we need to be really careful while implementing Queue Apex.**